# AWS Lambda dependency error for node-minizip

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm trying to upload my node project to AWS Lambda, but when I test it I'm getting this error from the lambda console:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "/var/lang/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /var/task/node_modules/node-minizip/build/Release/node-minizip.node)",
  "errorType": "Error",
  "stackTrace": [
    "Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:597:18)",
    "Module.load (module.js:487:32)",
    "tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)",
    "Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)",
    "Module.require (module.js:497:17)",
    "require (internal/module.js:20:19)",
    "Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/node-minizip/main.js:1:80)",
    "Module._compile (module.js:570:32)",
    "Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)"
  ]
}
```

It seems like there is a missing, non-node library that it is trying to run on, but I can't seem to find out how to fix that on the Lambda side. It runs just fine on my computer. I'm using node-minizip in an express to unzip a file that I grab programmatically. I tried switching to a few other modules but `node unzip` and `node-unzipper` cause some strange errors within the `express.js` core directories. Worst-case scenario I can hunt for a new module but I would love for this one to work out.

Any ideas on how to fix this error? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

bad luck for you. 
Minizip use a native lib "zlib", 
usually, you have 2 way of managing native :

- compile the lib when you build your application (this need compilation tools on your server)
- download the native lib corresponding to your OS at setup time. ( the build need to be the most generic possible to prevent incompatibility)

The minizip compile itself a native module when you install it. This means that if you compile on a computer with the latest version possible of kernel / libC / libC++ ...  you can use feature that will not be there on your server, and you end up with your issue.

So if you have modules that use a native library you'd better build your application in an environment similar to the server application will be executed.

Amazon provide an AMI that mimic lambda environment, generate your deployment zip file from that and deploy it. It should be ok.

Comment: Unfortunate... Thanks though, I'll try to find another module

Comment: I'm not sure this is completely right.  Amazon [provides an AMI of the base Lambda environment](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/current-supported-versions.html) so you can compile modules in a matching VM.  Wouldn't that be the way to solve this, @wargre?

Comment: Oups so sorry !  I edited my answer. There is multiple ways to deploy on lambda, there is one you can deploy the full zip file, so you deploy native lib with that. If you build your application on a server that have same library level it will be ok.